# Data binding not working and cannot see any error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am following a tutorial on WPF from msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx). I am not getting any error but no output either. **I wish to see the data in the ListBox from the properties that are assigned in the code.** I am pasting both of my xaml and cs file below. Any help in this regards is appreciated. I would appreciate if someone could refer me to some tutorials on WPF other than msdn.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Practice_1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Practice_1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>

</Window.Resources>

<ListBox Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartPrice}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    namespace Practice_1
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<AuctionItem> AuctionItemObjects;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            AuctionItemObjects = new List<AuctionItem>()
            {
                new AuctionItem()
                {
                    Description = "Inside C#. second edition",
                    StartDate = "8/8/2016",
                    StartPrice = "1000",
                    Category = "Books",
                    OwnerName = "Chummi",
                    MemberSince = "2004",
                    OwnerRating = "15",
                    SpecialFeatures = "Color",
                    CurrentPrice = "10"

                },
                new AuctionItem()
                {
                    Description = "Laptop - only 1 year old",
                    StartDate = "8/9/2016",
                    StartPrice = "100",
                    Category = "Electronics",
                    OwnerName = "Mark",
                    MemberSince = "2005",
                    OwnerRating = "10",
                    SpecialFeatures = "Highlight"
                },
                new AuctionItem()
                {
                    Description = "TV Drama Series",
                    StartDate = "8/10/2016",
                    StartPrice = "400",
                    Category = "DVDs",
                    OwnerName = "Chuhaan",
                    MemberSince = "2006",
                    OwnerRating = "5",
                    SpecialFeatures = ""
                },
                new AuctionItem()
                {
                    Description = "My DVD Collection",
                    StartDate = "8/11/2016",
                    StartPrice = "5000",
                    Category = "DVDs",
                    OwnerName = "Charsi",
                    MemberSince = "2008",
                    OwnerRating = "35",
                    SpecialFeatures = "Highlight"
                },

            };
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public class AuctionItem
        {

            public string Description { get; set; }

            public string StartPrice { get; set; }

            public string StartDate { get; set; }

            public string Category { get; set; }

            public string SpecialFeatures { get; set; }

            public string OwnerName { get; set; }

            public string OwnerRating { get; set; }

            public string MemberSince { get; set; }

            public string CurrentPrice { get; set; }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You aren't binding your `ListBox` to anything. How do you expect it to know which collection it's supposed to show if you don't tell it?

Comment: <ListBox Width="Auto" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Source ?? ">

Can you please tell me what I should write because I have tried few things none of them are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your `ListBox` to your collection.

Something like:

```
<ListBox Width="Auto" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding AuctionItemObjects}">
```

Otherwise how does it know what you want in your `ListBox`?

Note a couple of things however:

- Usually it's better to have a *model* and a *view model*. The view model would be the `DataContext` for your *view* (which is your window). This is the MVVM pattern and you should learn it.
- Your `List<T>` won't update your `ListBox` when you add or remove items from the underlying list. This is because it doesn't implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), if you need that, consider `ObservableCollection<T>`
- None of the properties in your `AuctionItem` will update the UI when they change either because your are not implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
- `AuctionItemObjects` needs to be a property, not a field. WPF won't bind fields, so `public List<AuctionItem> AuctionItemObjects {get; set; }`

Comment: @stalbaig: You need a property, not a field (last bullet)

Comment: Thanks for the detail reply.

Please lets just first help me in displaying those items, I will try to implement the change notifications afterwards. For my learning I first want to clear this hurdle
I have used your syntax for "ItemsSource= {Binding AuctionItemObjects}" but it is not working.

Comment: @stalbaig: Did you change your `AuctionItemObjects` to a *property*?